Что является constraint в ISO 9899:2024?
Предлагаю своё понимание дискуссии StackOverflow. Цитата из раздела 4. Conformance указанного стандарта:

If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

Правильно ли я понял, опираясь на источники, что здесь имеется в виду следующее: undefined behavior появляется всегда при нарушении правил, которые перечислены в секции constraints (где она в текущем стандарте, я не нашёл), а также при нарушении любого ограничения shall или  shall not за пределами правил указанной секции? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как понимать приведённую цитату.

кмк есть тонкая грань между "behavior is undefined" и "undefined behavior"

@SergeyTatarintsev, далее по тексту в стандарте идёт утверждение о том, что это одно и то же. Если необходимо и у меня есть такое право, могу опубликовать дополнительно продолжение цитаты.

Вроде бы в оригинальном вопросе и ответе всё верно объяснено. Если существует constraint и он нарушается, то даже если явно сказано что это UB, то должна быть диагностика; если не сказано что UB, то тем более. Если constraint не указан, но при этом нарушается фраза с shall или shall not, то это UB, диагностика не обязательна.
